# How to create hierarchical partitions for batch data in Hive

Tags: hive, schema

consider 2000 year data.

### test.csv

```
country_code,product_code,rpt_period
us,crd,2000
us,pcl,2000
us,mtg,2000
in,crd,2000
in,pcl,2000
in,mtg,2000
```

now i am appending newly generated 2001 records to test.csv. after appending new data to test.csv my data looks like below.

### append.csv

```
country_code,product_code,rpt_period
us,crd,2000
us,pcl,2000
us,mtg,2000
in,crd,2000
in,pcl,2000
in,mtg,2000
us,crd,2001
us,pcl,2001
us,mtg,2001
in,crd,2001
in,pcl,2001
in,mtg,2001
```

Below scenarios are possible in the hive? If yes, please answer questions.

1. How to create schema for Partition table `Foo` using this data?. and also I
       want partition columns as *country_code* and *product_code.*
2. For instance, i want to load (from test.csv file records) to table `Foo`? using hive `LOAD DATA` comand ?
3. How to load append.csv (only 2001 records) to table `Foo`. this also needs to be done using hive `LOAD DATA` command

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, All the scenarios you have mentioned are possible with Hive.

1. Create temp table and load all the data you have and the you can create partitioned table with 2 columns you have mentioned.

For 2 and 3: Just the load command will work. If your intention is to load into partitioned table you have to go via creating temp table and insert into partitioned table.

Let me know this is what you want else update your question.

Comment: for question 2& 3: instead of creating a temp table and Insert into the partition, I want to use LOAD command load data into partition table from respective files test.csv and append.csv. possible?

Comment: No, with hive queries(load data)... But there is a tweak, you can directly place required data into the partitioned folder but make sure you are placing the right data(as per the partition).